# Use a single collection to hold all parameters

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I take user input on a form and bind it to a parameter which will then tie to my report. Can I use a single collection to hold all of my parameters? It seems redundant to have to create a collection and a parameter for every item I want to pass to my report.

---

To make this work the way I require, I've had to add a collection for each param on my form:

```
// #1 Setup a collections
    ParameterValues firstNameCollection = new ParameterValues();
    ParameterValues lastNameCollectoin = new ParameterValues();
```

Then I created the actual parameter:

```
// #2 Set the parameters
    ParameterDiscreteValue firstNameParam = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
    ParameterDiscreteValue lastNameParam = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
```

Bound the value:

```
// #3 Set the values
    firstNameParam.Value = "First Name";
    lastNameParam.Value = "Last Name";
```

Added the parameters to the collection:

```
// #4 Add the parameters to the collection
    firstNameCollection.Add(firstNameParam);
    lastNameCollectoin.Add(lastNameParam);
```

And applied the collections to the form:

```
// #5 Apply the collections to the report
    MyReport.DataDefinition.ParameterFields["FirstName"].ApplyCurrentValues(firstNameCollection);
    MyReport.DataDefinition.ParameterFields["LastName"].ApplyCurrentValues(lastNameCollectoin);
```

Comment: couldn't understand, Can you elaborate? `Single collection to hold all parameters` part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to fill a Crystal Report Parameter in C#.

```
MyReport.SetParameterValue("NameOfReportParam", Object);
```

In the initial question, I was **creating the parameter** vs **referencing it** as shown here.